# Signalr response from client

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, signalr, signalr.client

How do I get the result into my action from my subscribed client?

I have setup hub in my mvc application with signalr with purpose to validate clients between multiple clients providers.

which I am accessing in my controller as:

```
IHubContext _hubContext = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<AmsHub>();
```

and my mvc action

```
  public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var result = _hubContext.Clients.All.FindUsers("johny brown");
// how do I access the result?
        return View();
    }
```

My subscribed client ( I have multiple ) with implementation

```
 var hubConnection = new HubConnection(hubUrl);
 IHubProxy myHubProxy = hubConnection.CreateHubProxy("AmsHub");


 myHubProxy.On("FindUsers", (name) =>
      {
         var foundRecords = new User()
          {
             FirstName = "Johny",
             LastName = "Brown",
             Email = "johny.brown@dummy.com",
          };
     });
```

Comment: What is currently happening?

Comment: I want to return the found records to the caller (my mvc application) but do not know how

Comment: `_hubContext.Clients.All` send signalr messages to all clients. So `FindUsers` just a dynamic method it will not find any user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no return values in SignalR (from Client to Server). You can define a FindUsersCallback function and call it at your Client. On Server side you handle this "Signal" and give your View() back.

```
myHubProxy.On("FindUsers", (name) =  > {
        var foundRecords = new User() {
            FirstName = "Johny",
            LastName = "Brown",
            Email = "johny.brown@dummy.com",
        };

        hubConnection.asmHub.FindUsersCallback(foundRecords);
    });
```

Comment: There are starting in .NET7 https://learn.microsoft.com/sv-se/aspnet/core/signalr/hubs?view=aspnetcore-7.0#client-results